# Kramers-Kronig relations for geometric series

Tags: complex-numbers, greens-functions, correlation-functions, analyticity

Suppose $\phi(z)$ is an analytic function in the upper complex plane, so it satisfies the Kramers-Kronig relations, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\Re\phi(w) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{\Im\phi(x)}{x-w} dx
\end{equation}
where $w$ and $x$ are real variables.
My question is if I define another function
\begin{equation}
F(w) = \frac{1}{1+\phi(w)}
\end{equation}
whether the real part and imaginary part of $F(w)$ still satisfies the Kramers–Kronig relations?

From my understanding, since I can rewrite the equation as
\begin{equation}
F(w) = \frac{1}{1+\phi(w)} = 1 - \phi(w) + \phi^2(w) - \phi^3(w) + \phi^4(w) + \cdots
\end{equation}
$F(w)$ is still analytic in the upper complex plane, which means Kramers–Kronig relations still holds for $F(w)$.
However, I checked it numerically, (just took an concrete example of $\phi$ the electron-hole bubble) the relations breaks down in this situation. What's the reason of this?

Comment: $F$ has a pole whenever $\phi$ becomes $-1$ at some point, so it is definitely not analytic in general.

Comment: Do you mean that $1/(1+\phi)$ and its geometric expansion are not equivalent in this case?

Comment: The expansion you wrote down clearly does not converge for $\phi(w)=-1$. So you cannot use this to prove analiticity of the LHS even though every term is analytic on its own (but as I said, the problem was already obvious without a series expansion).